# Advice on how I can make my own 1 cal cooking spray like frylight

Tags: food-safety, oil, spoilage, olive-oil

I've been using frylight for years, but I'm trying to swap to a healthier version with no chemicals.

I've been doing some research on the internet and some people have talked about making their own version by getting a spray bottle and mixing 1 part olive oil to 7 parts water. Then just shaking the bottle well before each use. However I'm concerned that the lack of preservatives could mean that the water will go stale and will be dangerous to drink.

Has anyone done this or can you offer any advice for the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Water and oil plus heat sounds like splattering.

Comment: Which chemicals in frylight do you want to avoid?

Answer (score 5):

Why not just pick whatever oil you want to use, put some on a paper towel and wipe the pan with it? It'll have the same affect or just skip the oil all together and get a really good non-stick pan?

The only way to get oil and water to mix is to use an emulsifier.

Comment: Even a teaspoon of olive oil is 40 calories

Answer (score 2):

According to [Frylights website](http://www.frylight.co.uk/) the products are mostly oil, and have at least 30% less fat and calories than regular oil. The reason they can call it 1 calorie, is that each spray is so small.

The simplest way to do what you are trying to, is to reuse one of the Frylight bottles, filling it with the oil of your choice and using about 2/3 as much, i.e. instead of 5 or 6 pumps do only 4.

Comment: There might be surficants in the product, making it so that less oil will coat a larger surface.  If that's the case, just replacing it with oil and using less might not give the desired effect.